# Adding node to xml using java getting unexpected result?

Tags: java, xml, xmlnode

This is my demo.jsp page

```
String filename = "TestNode.xml";
ServletContext app = getServletContext();
String projectPath = app.getRealPath("/");
String result = projectPath + filename;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(result)));
Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
Element element1 = doc.getDocumentElement();
Element element2 = doc.createElement("hai");
rootElement.appendChild(element2);
Element name = doc.createElement("welcome");
element2.appendChild(name);
element1.appendChild(element2);
DOMSource src = new DOMSource(doc);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = null;
transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
StreamResult rslt = new StreamResult(result);
transformer.transform(src, rslt);
```

for this i'm getting output as:

```
<root>    
    <hai>
        <welcome/>
    </hai>
</root>
```

but expected output is:

```
<root>    
    <hai>
        <welcome>
        </welcome>
    </hai>
</root>
```

Where should I change the code to get expected result?

Comment: It effectively means the exact same thing, it is tidying because welcome has no content nested inside it, is there any reason  you need the expected result over what you are getting? (<welcome/> means the exact same thing as <welcome></welcome> just neater)

Comment: I'm getting <root>    
    <hai>
        <welcome/>
    </hai>
</root> but out put needs <root>    
    <hai>
        <welcome>
        </welcome>
    </hai>
</root>

Comment: what do you mean "but out put needs" what needs it to be in this format? I can't imagine any validation ever failing this.

Comment: for the above code I'm getting output <root><hai><welcome/></hai></root> observe the <welcome/> node its incorrect.to get output after <hai> node <welcome>node should come and close the</welcome>node this way i need it.

Comment: `<welcome/>` and `<welcome></welcome>` are **completely identical to the XML parser**. See [XML Scpecification: 3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags): "[Definition: An element with no content is said to be empty.] The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag. [Definition: An empty-element tag takes a special form: [44] EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'"

Comment: to get output like this what should i add in my code.<root>    
    <hai>
        <welcome>
        </welcome>
    </hai>
</root>

Comment: @ThazAhammad If you want to have whitespace between the `<welcome>` tags (which is not the same as empty), then you have to add a text node as a child of that element.

Comment: that only i need it,could you please tell me how to add child node to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the output:

```
<root>    
    <hai>
        <welcome>
        </welcome>
    </hai>
</root>
```

Where the `<welcome> </welcome>` element is actually not empty but contains at least one whitespace character, you need to create a text node and add it as the child of the `welcome` element:

```
Element name = doc.createElement("welcome");

Node textNode = doc.createTextNode(" ");
name.appendChild(textNode);

element2.appendChild(name);
```

Comment: if possible could you please integrate this with my above code

Comment: I just added the two lines in the middle. The first line and the last are from your code. You could even do it in *one* line of you want: `name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(" "));`. Just place it after the `Element name = doc.createElement("welcome");` in *your* code.